# How to send a Parse push notification without an alert?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

I am sending a push notification from parse, using cloud code. The problem is I don't want any sort of alert because I am only using the push notification to trigger a method in other peoples applications.

How can I send a push notification without **any sort of alert** I want it to be purely in the background?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my current code, how can I do it without any sort of alert?

```
PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];
        [pushQuery whereKey:@"userId" containedIn:friendArray];

        // Send push notification to query
        PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
        [push setQuery:pushQuery]; // Set our Installation query
        [push setMessage:nil];
        [push sendPushInBackground];
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

1. If you set `[push setMessage:""];` to look exactly like that, the notification won't pop up outside of the application.
2. Comment out or get rid of `[PFPush handlePush:userInfo];` so the notification won't pop up inside the app.

Push notifications will now still trigger the `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo` method, however there will be NO alert what so ever :)

Now you can call methods without alerts using push notifications.